# Not able to get the correct result when using reduce function to create a new object from array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

Here is my try, I am trying to create a new object from array value, but getting result as: `two` instead of new object. any one help me to understand the  reduce function clearly?

```js
const arr = ['one', 'two']

function fn() {
  return arr.reduce((obj, val) => obj[val] = val , {});
}

console.log(fn()); 

//expecting: {one:'one', two:'two'} but getting 'two'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function returns `val` (last processed element) instead of `obj` (accumulator), try:

```js
const arr = ['one', 'two']

function fn() {
  return arr.reduce((obj, val) => { obj[val] = val; return obj; } , {});
}

console.log(fn());
```